# Update panel and script managar not working in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have converted my web application from 3.5 to 4.0. I have been getting the issue on update panel post back method. I have linkbutton and textboxes inside the same update panel, when clicking on linkbutton for fill the values system throw below JS error.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 5 Aug 2010 15:12:05 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 416
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://sandbox.sitters.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=yIeIveNSIovIHEMZHoL7xnSA7yz8Oq2kjqMmaZ6_5G_YTaj7tV0DfcI2dxh1Bg6iJAZ8d1ATJwb0KFlZa_StIw2&t=487a7f9a

Please let me know if any one faced the same issue.

thanks

Comment: Is it a server error?  If you put a breakpoint in the click event, do you get there?  Server errors with AJAX still appear a client-side JS errors...

Comment: `Object doesn't support this property or method` is typically a JavaScript exception.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax in net 4.0 is conflicted with some custom javascript code and some framework such as: prototypejs. Remove them. If this problem is still appear, you have to check your other javascript files for the functions

My problem is same as you.I spent a few hours to fix it. And it works.

good luck.
Lai